# z-index of child element of a flex item

Tags: html, css, flexbox, z-index

I want an absolute positioned child element (`.tag-preview-container`) of a flex item (`.image-container`) to overlap other elements in the DOM (for instance the header `.header`). I'm setting the `z-index` of the absolute positioned element to be 2 (even 1 should work). However, the element doesn't overlap any DOM element outside the flex container(`.tags-panel`). In fact, it is completely cut off by the container. I am not setting z-index of any other element in the DOM, so the root should be the stacking context.

```
<div class="panel-container">
  <div class="header">

  </div>
  <div class="tags-panel">
    <div class="image-container">
      <div class="tag-preview-container">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">

    </div>
    <div class="image-container">

    </div>
    <div class="image-container">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the scss code and here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ug3qn6mb/1/)

```
.panel-container {
    width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  .header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: green;
  }
  .tags-panel {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    top: 40px;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    align-content: flex-start;
  }
}

.image-container {
  flex: 0 0 33%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-left: 1px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  .tag-preview-container {
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 2;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The `z-index` is affected by the `overflow` property in `.tags-panel`, removing `overflow-y: auto;` will solve the issue. Here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/yc5xanax/

`overflow-y: auto;` will automatically wrap/hide the content outside the `.tags-panel` container.

Comment: You are right. I totally forgot about that property. That makes complete sense. Thank you!